How can i connect to my outlook 365 account with 2FA enabled in my php function in order to grab details from email and store in db?
What I am looking to accomplish:

I want to be able to connect my app to the outlook 365 email account
Parse data in the email, such as headers/body of email
Send that data and store it in my db

Problem: I cannot seem to get connected to my outlook account using 2 factor. I have all of the proper azure credentials. I have php-ews installed and am using that library. I had my code working with a default mail client but that was without 2 factor with using only username/password. (not as secure)
Here is the current code, Its all in one file i am using for testing, i edited the NTLMSoapClient class to try to add the necessary details. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'class.connect.php';
require 'monitor.php';

use garethp\ews\API;
use garethp\ews\API\NTLMSoapClient;

class OAuthSoapClient extends NTLMSoapClient
{
    private $accessToken;

    public function __construct($location, $auth, $wsdl, array $options = [], $accessToken)
    {
        $this->accessToken = $accessToken;
        parent::__construct($location, $auth, $wsdl, $options);
    }

    protected function setupHeaders($location, $action)
    {
        $headers = parent::setupHeaders($location, $action);
        $headers[] = new \SoapHeader('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext', 
'Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->accessToken);
        return $headers;
    }
}

Here is the function that handles the email credentials:
public function processEmailData() {
    $server = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx';
    $tenant = 'Tenant';
    $clientId = 'clientID';
    $clientSecret = 'secret';
    $tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->post($tokenUrl, [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                'client_id' => $clientId,
                'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
                'scope' => 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default'
            ]
        ]);

        $tokenData = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        $accessToken = $tokenData['access_token'];
        $this->logger->log('INFO', 'Access token retrieved successfully');
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->logger->log('ERROR', "Failed to retrieve access token: " . $ex->getMessage());
        die('Cannot retrieve access token: ' . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $authOptions = [];
    $wsdl = null;

    $options = [
        'version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => 1,
    ];

    // Initialize OAuthSoapClient with appropriate parameters
    $client = new OAuthSoapClient($server, $authOptions, $wsdl, $options, $accessToken);
    $api = new API($client);

try {
        $this->logger->log('INFO', 'Connected to Microsoft Exchange server successfully');

        // Define the folder to search (e.g., inbox)
        $folder = new \garethp\ews\API\Type\DistinguishedFolderIdType();
        $folder->setId(\garethp\ews\API\Enumeration\DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX);

        // Wrap the folder ID in a NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType
        $folderArray = new \garethp\ews\API\Type\NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
        $folderArray->setDistinguishedFolderId([$folder]);

        // Define the item response shape
        $itemShape = new \garethp\ews\API\Type\ItemResponseShapeType();
        $itemShape->setBaseShape('AllProperties');

        // Create the find item request
        $request = new \garethp\ews\API\Message\FindItemType();
        $request->setParentFolderIds($folderArray);
        $request->setItemShape($itemShape);
        $request->setTraversal(\garethp\ews\API\Enumeration\ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW);

        // Fetch unread emails
        $this->logger->log('INFO', 'Attempting to fetch unread emails');
        $response = $api->getClient()->findItem($request);
        $this->logger->log('INFO', 'Fetch unread emails request sent successfully');

        // Check if response contains items
        $responseMessages = $response->getResponseMessages();
        if (!empty($responseMessages)) {
            $findItemResponse = $responseMessages[0]->getFindItemResponseMessage();
            $items = $findItemResponse->getRootFolder()->getItems()->getMessage();
            $this->logger->log('INFO', 'Fetched unread emails');
        } else {
            $this->logger->log('INFO', 'No unread emails found');
            return;
        }

        // Processing emails in batches of 10
        $batchSize = 10;
        $batches = array_chunk($items, $batchSize);

        foreach ($batches as $batch) {
            foreach ($batch as $item) {
                $mailId = $item->getItemId()->getId();
                $this->logger->log('DEBUG', "Fetched email with ID: $mailId");

                if ($this->isEmailProcessed($mailId)) {
                    $this->logger->log('INFO', "Email already processed for UID: $mailId. Skipping.");
                    continue;
                }

                $sender = $item->getFrom()->getMailbox()->getEmailAddress();
                $this->logger->log('DEBUG', "Sender email extracted: $sender");

                // Verify the sender email address
                if (!$this->isValidSender($sender)) {
                    $this->logger->log('WARN', "Invalid sender email: $sender");
                    continue;
                }

                // Mark the email as read
                $api->getClient()->updateItem($item, ['IsRead' => true]);

                // debugging
                //$this->logger->log('INFO', "Processing email from: $sender");

                // Extract the actual sender email address
                $replyTo = $this->getReplyTo($item);

                // Mark this email as processed
                $this->markEmailAsProcessed($mailId);
                $this->logger->log('INFO', "Marked email as processed for UID: $mailId");

                // Add a separator line to visually show where the next transaction starts
                $this->logger->log('INFO', str_repeat('-', 50));
            }

            // Sleep for a short duration to avoid overloading the server
            usleep(500000); // 0.5 second
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->logger->log('ERROR', "Microsoft Exchange connection failed: " . $ex->getMessage());
        die('Cannot connect to Microsoft Exchange: ' . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}


Any reason you don't use the SDK provided by Microsoft? Probably easier than trying to roll your own, for stuff like this. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php . You can do lots of Outlook stuff via Graph without needing the legacy EWS API
